How to make text-decoration-style: double in WebKit?
I need to create double underline (without using border!!!) in webkit.
This is my code


<!DOCTYPE html><html>
    <body>
    <span style="-webkit-text-decoration-line: underline;-webkit-text-decoration-style: double;-webkit-text-decoration-color: red;color: red">
        Text 1
    </span><br>
    <span style="text-decoration-line: underline;text-decoration-style: double;text-decoration-color: red;color: red">
        Text 2
    </span><br>
    </body></html>



And this is the result

I use webkit engine in JavaFX and its version is: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/617.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) JavaFX/23 Safari/617 , based on GTK WebKit 2.42.x.
I found this issue where they say that -webkit-text-decoration-style: double; is supported, the date of the issue is 2017.
Could anyone say how to make it work? I really can't understand why such simple code doesn't work in 2024.
